# JAVA- Error reading file 1 (error)

Tags: java, input, file-io, bufferedreader

I am trying to read a txt file and trying to save it in an array.
following is the format of the txt file:

`A B 5`
`A C 2`
`A D 4`
`.....`

```
public class search {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        try {  

            Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in); // for user input            
            System.out.println("Enter the file name: ");
            String filename1 = user_input.next();

            File file = new File(filename1);

            search bd = new search();
            Node[] nodes;
            nodes = bd.getNodes(file);
            bd.printNodes(nodes);

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file " + e.getMessage());
        } 
    }    

    public Node[] getNodes(File file) throws IOException {
        FileReader bd = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(bd);
        String line;
        ArrayList<Node>list = new ArrayList<Node>(); 
        while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) { 
            String[] token = line.split(" "); // create string of tokens
            list.add(new Node(token[0], token[1], Integer.parseInt(token[2])));

        }
        bufferReader.close(); 

        return list.toArray(new Node[list.size()]); // converting list to array
    }

    public void printNodes(Node[] nodes) {
        System.out.println("======================");

        for(Node node : nodes) {
            System.out.println(node);
        }
        System.out.println("======================");
    }
```

Following is my Node class

```
class Node {

    String leftchild;
    String rightchild;
    int cost;

    public Node(){

    }

    public Node(String firstchild, String secondchild, int cost){
        this.leftchild = firstchild;
        this.rightchild = secondchild;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public Node(String firstchild, String secondchild) {
        this.leftchild = firstchild;
        this.rightchild = secondchild;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getChildren(){
        ArrayList<String> childNodes = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(this.leftchild != null)
        {
            childNodes.add(leftchild);
        }
        if(this.rightchild != null) {
            childNodes.add(rightchild);
        }
        return childNodes;
    }

    public boolean removeChild(Node n){
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return leftchild +" "+ rightchild;
    }

}
```

I have no compiling issues, but when I run my code, it is giving me error as

> error reading file 1

Not sure why. I have tried to change my code in many ways but none of them worked. Could anyone please figure this out for me?
Thanks

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace();` in the catch blocks to display the full error message.

Comment: Yes I have now used it and found the error to be `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` 
So I am guessing there is something problem with my `printNodes`method?

Comment: No need to guess when you can use Google.

Comment: I have googled it, but can't seem how to fix it :/

Comment: The stacktrace gives you the linenumber of the exception, and if you really did google, you should know what an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means.

Comment: Also, this is the third time I see this exact question. Which school is giving this out as homework?

Comment: @Kayaman maybe the stackoverflow academy :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`, it means that you have at least one line in your test input file that doesn't contain any spaces.

Indeed in your code you do `String[] token = line.split(" ")` which will extract all the tokens separated by a space and put them into an array of `String`, so if you get this error it means that the `length` of the array is `1` such that you cannot access to `token[1]` as it refers to the second element of your `array` that only contains one element.

So in your case you should test first if the `length` of the array has the right `length` as next:

```
String[] token = line.split(" "); // create string of tokens
if (token.length >= 3) {
    list.add(new Node(token[0], token[1], Integer.parseInt(token[2])));
}
```

Comment: Could you please be a bit specific?

Comment: Oh okay sorry let me check

Comment: response improved to give you a way to avoid it

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked. But however it is not printing my token[2] (cost). It is just giving me the first two tokens of strings. What could be the reason to it?

Comment: because it is not added in your toString method, try return leftchild + " " + rightchild + " " + cost;

Comment: I now clearly understood :) You are awesome. Thanks so much